# Error "Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked" when using ckeditor 5 with livewire v3

Tags: laravel

I get "**Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked**" error when using it. Please help me fix it.

```
JS: ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#content'))
                .then(editor => {
                    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                        console.log(editor.getData());
                        var content = editor.getData();
                        Livewire.dispatch('updateContent', content); // Gửi sự kiện đến Livewire
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

```
console.log(editor.getData()); // <p>a</p>
```

```
HTML: <div class="mb-4">
           <div wire:ignore>
             <label class="form-label" for="content">Content</label>
             <textarea type="text" id="content" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid @enderror" wire:model.live.debounce.300ms="content" name="content" placeholder="Enter content"></textarea>
            </div>
            @error('content')
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
            @enderror
      </div>
```

```
PHP Livewire: #[On('updateContent')]
    public function updateContent($newContent)
    {
        dd('hi');
        $this->content = $newContent; 
    }
```

Fix Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked

Comment: Same issue here without ckeditor. Is the url /livewire/update?

Comment: any luck finding a solution to this? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
Livewire.dispatch('updateContent', content);
```

to this:

```
Livewire.dispatch('updateContent', { text: content});
```

and change this:

```
#[On('updateContent')]
public function updateContent($newContent)
{
    dd('hi');
    $this->content = $newContent; 
}
```

to this:

```
#[On('updateContent')]
public function updateContent($text)
{
    dd('hi');
    $this->content = $text; 
}
```